# Why does get_object_vars return private and protected properties within a static method

Tags: php, static-methods, access-modifiers

The [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function is supposedly scope-sensitive, in that it will only return properties to which it has access to in the current scope.

Given the following crude example, why does the function call return all three properties regardless of their visibility?

```
<?php

class A
{
    private $b = 'foo';
    protected $c = 'bar';
    public $d = 'baz';

    public static function getPublicProperties(\A $object)
    {
        return get_object_vars($object);
    }
}

$a = new \A();

var_dump(\A::getPublicProperties($a));
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  'b' =>
  string(3) "foo"
  'c' =>
  string(3) "bar"
  'd' =>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

The `getPublicProperties` method is static but is able to access the private and protected properties of the object passed in. Is this a bug in PHP?

Comment: As the object is of the type where the method is defined, you can access all of the data in that object.  If in `getPublicProperties` you tried to output `$object->b` it would work as the method has access to the classes private properties.  If you instead passed in class B object (changing the parameter type) then it wouldn't have access.

Comment: Thanks Nigel. I'm aware of the fact I could pass in a different type and just get the public properties. I just don't understand why a static method of a type would have access to instances of that type's private properties.